# Как мне установить собственный курсор?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qcursor

Я хочу установить собственную иконку курсора, которая должна меняться при наведении на определённый объект или тип объекта

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)

        block = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        block.resize(100, 100)
        block.setStyleSheet('background:red;cursor : url("1.png"), auto;')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Когда мышка находится на виджете срабатывает `enterEvent`, в нем выполняем `setOverrideCursor(тут создаем свой курсор)` из  `QApplication`, когда выходит срабатывает `leaveEvent`, в нем выполняем `restoreOverrideCursor()` из `QApplication`. [Как сделать свой курсор](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455584/cross-platform-custom-cursors-for-qt-cursor-in-resource-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cursor : QCursor` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#cursor-prop

Это свойство содержит форму курсора для этого виджета.
Курсор мыши примет эту форму, когда окажется над этим виджетом.

```
QWidget.setCursor(const QCursor &)
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)

        block = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        block.resize(100, 100)
#        block.setStyleSheet('background:red;  cursor: url("im.png"), auto;')
        block.setStyleSheet('background:red;')
        
        block.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.CrossCursor))              # <-----


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**Update**

я засомневался, что мой первые ответ, это то что вы хотели.
Вот второй вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)

        block = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        block.resize(100, 100)
        block.setStyleSheet('background: #5f9;') #cursor : url("1.png"), auto;')
        
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('_+_.png').scaled(80, 80) 
        cursor = QtGui.QCursor(pixmap)
        block.setCursor(cursor)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**`_+_.png`**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]